# Using Recursion with Username matching

Tags: java, string, recursion, matching

I am implementing a String matching algorithm for a username database. My method takes an existing Username database and a new username that the person wants and it checks to see if the username is taken. if it is taken the method is supposed to return the username with a number that isn't taken in the database.

Example:

"Justin","Justin1", "Justin2", "Justin3"

Enter "Justin"

return: "Justin4"
since Justin and Justin with the numbers 1 thru 3 are already taken.

In my code sample below, `newMember` returns Justin1 even though it already exists--where is the mistake?

```
public class UserName {

    static int j = 0;

    static String newMember(String[] existingNames, String newName){
        boolean match = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < existingNames.length; i++){
            if(existingNames[i] == (newName)){
                match = true;
            }

        }
        if(match){
            j++;
            return newMember(existingNames, newName + j);
        }
        else{
            return newName; 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[] userNames = new String[9];
        userNames[0] = "Justin1";
        userNames[1] = "Justin2";
        userNames[2] = "Justin3";
        userNames[3] = "Justin";

        System.out.println(newMember(userNames, "Justin"));

        // I don't understand why it returns Justin1 when the name is already taken 
        // in the array.
    }
}
```

Comment: [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: You have done the same old mistake, that has been resolved about a thousands times on SO.

Comment: Why use recursion for this?

Comment: @Ruchira its in his code. For future reference, please include question in your post outside of your code, OP.

Comment: First thing is first, please indent your code properly so it's easy enough to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
if(existingNames[i] == (newName)){
```

Should become

```
if(existingNames[i].equals(newName)){
```

In general, always use `equals` instead of `==` for Strings in Java.

Comment: I used Equals but I get a null pointer exception. I don't understand what causes the null pointer exception

Comment: @user2510809 Your array has length 9 but you're only filling in 4 values. Try changing the length of the array to 4?

Comment: @user2510809 Or don't use an array at all and use a `List` instead.

Comment: @arshajii yes that would be even better, just trying to fix the immediate problem :)

Comment: Should probably use .equalsIgnoreCase()

Answer (score 1):

I would change your approach to this. I think it would be better to use a `Map<String, Integer>`. For example, the fact that `"Justin"` - `"Justin3"` are taken usernames can be represented by the map:

```
{"Justin": 3}
```

To check if a username is taken, check if it's a key in the map. To get the "next" username for a specific taken username, get the value corresponding to the name from the map and add 1. Something like this:

```
static String newMember(Map<String, Integer> existingNames, String newName) {
    if (existingNames.containsKey(newName)) {
        int newNum = existingNames.get(newName) + 1;
        existingNames.put(newName, newNum);
        return newName + newNum;
    }

    existingNames.put(newName, 0);
    return newName;    
}
```

Oh, and use `.equals()` instead of `==` when comparing strings :)

Comment: @boxed__l What do you mean?

Comment: Aren't you splitting `justin4` into `justin(key):4(value)` ?

Comment: @boxed__l Not really: the map holds the username:max_number pairs, where max_number is the largest number attached to that username so far.

Comment: this is a very interesting approach I will try this. But didn't you mean to put an else statement after the If statement?

Comment: @user2510809 No, since there is a `return` at the end of the `if`-clause.

Comment: oh so a return ends the function immediately ?

Comment: @user2510809 Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

You're not comparing the strings correctly, and you're adding the integer 1 to a string. Comparing strings is done with .equals. In order to concatenate the integer onto the end of the string:

```
static Integer j=0;

return newMember(existingNames, newName + j.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing strings in Java, you should generally use the [equals()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) methods to do so.

Answer (score 0):

**Never ever compare equality of Strings with `==`. use `equals()` **

Answer (score 0):

Use `.equals` to compare strings in Java, not `==`.

`==` will determine if the string references are the same which they almost certainly will not be. (There are rare cases when they may be due to the intern pool.)

`.equals` will determine if the **content** of the strings are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using `==` with strings compares the references, not the underlying objects. Use `str.equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a function somewhere in your application answering if a username already exists, I call this `usernameExists(String username)` returning `true` or `false`.

```
String getOkUsername (String wantedUsername) {
  //if it's free, return it!
  if(!usernameExists(wantedUsername)) {
      return wantedUsername;
  };

  //OK, already taken, check for next available username 
  int i=1;
  while(usernameExists(wantedUsername+Integer.toString(i))) {
      i++;}
  return wantedUsername + Integer.toString(i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is much easier to do it in SQL:

```
select ... where ... LIKE username%
```